# php if table exists delete mysql

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I'm contemplating on a small script in php mysql to delete a row if it exists in the database but doesn't exist in the update.
Please let me know if i'm going in the right direction.

Heres what happens...

An uploaded file from which i get the information with all data, it is then Inserted to the mysql database, or updated if already exists.
What i'm trying to do is if the uploaded file doesn't have whats in the database (as it's been updated) then Delete the row what is there.

AGENT_REF in the database is the Primary Key

```
$sql_archeck = mysql_query ("SELECT AGENT_REF FROM epsales");
while($check = mysql_fetch_array($sql_archeck) {
    if ($check["AGENT_REF"] == $agentref) {

    }
}
```

I hope i've explained clearly, my head not on right today..lol
Thank you for your time with this and any assistance is highly appriciated!

UPDATE

For eg, say the file uploaded has info as:

```
AGENT_REF = 1
AGENT_REF = 2
AGENT_REF = 3
AGENT_REF = 5
```

but in the database:

```
AGENT_REF = 1
AGENT_REF = 2
AGENT_REF = 3
AGENT_REF = 4
AGENT_REF = 5
```

I want to Delete AGENT_REF 4 from the database :)
Hope this update helps Thank you!

Comment: The English in your first line doesn't make sense... What are you asking for?

Comment: I'm wanting to delete from the database a row that isn't in the file uploaded... as in: 
AGENT_REF = 1
AGENT_REF = 2
AGENT_REF = 3
AGENT_REF = 5

As AGENT_REF 4 isn't in the list then delete from mysql as in the database AGENT_REF = 4 is present :)

Is this more understandable:)

Comment: Why don't you just flush your table and add new data from the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array_diff() is your friend.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

```
<?php

  $new_refs = array(
    /* load your new references into this array - you haven't said how you're managing them in your original post */
  );

$sql_archeck = mysql_query ("SELECT AGENT_REF FROM epsales");
  $check = mysql_fetch_array($sql_archeck);

  $dead_keys = array_diff($check, $new_refs);


/* $dead_keys now holds a list of keys which don't exist in the new data and you can delete them */

?>
```

EDIT: changed post from MYSQL's ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE answer to PHP array_diff() solution after reading comments on other posts explaining full requirement...

Comment: Thank you for this :) didn't know about array_diff... Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly, what you wanna do is use the REPLACE INTO function, she delete first and insert after... ??

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: Replace into would delete the record and add a new one :)
I just want to delete a record that isn't in the updated file uploaded but is in the database :) hope this helps